# C++ Spaces are not being read in my input file?

Tags: c++

```css
Input txt file:

Joe Smith
Mary Jones
Hamid Namdar

Desired Output Txt file:

Smith Joe
Jones Mary
Namdar Hamid

Output file I receive:

SmitJoeJonesMaryNamdarHamid
```

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 ofstream output;
 ifstream input;
 string firstname, lastname;

 output.open("LastName.txt");
 input.open("FirstName.txt");

 cout << "Processing Data..." << endl;

 input >> firstname >> lastname;

 cout << firstname << lastname << endl;

 output << lastname << firstname;

 cout << lastname << firstname << endl;

 input >> firstname >> lastname;

 cout << firstname << lastname << endl;

 output << lastname << firstname;

 cout << lastname << firstname << endl;

 input >> firstname >> lastname;

 cout << firstname << lastname << endl;

 output << lastname << firstname;

 cout << lastname << firstname << endl;


 input.close();
 output.close();

 cin.get();
 cin.get();

 return 0;

}
```

My program is required to have spaces between the names, and even though there is a space in my text document, the spaces are not being read. Does anyone have an idea on what I should do in order to have the spaces be read?

Comment: Please post the input file, the expected output, and the observed output.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you would like to see spaces in your output but you are not getting them. That makes you think that the spaces are not being read. The truth is that the white spaces are being read but are being discarded when you use:

```
input >> firstname >> lastname;
```

You need to change the lines that create the output to:

```
cout << firstname << " " << lastname << endl;
output << lastname << " " << firstname << endl;
```